# XmlSlurper/NekoHTML document fragment parsing - No HTML or BODY tags wanted

Tags: groovy, fragment, xmlslurper, cyberneko

Dear All, I am trying to parse the following HTML fragment, and I would like to get the same fragment as output (without HTML and BODY tags). Is this possible? If so, how?

Thank you
Misha

p.s. I am reading here:
http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/faq.html#fragments
and I believe I have added the correct options below. However, the output is still incorrect :(

Thank you
Misha

```
import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.util.XmlNodePrinter
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild


def text="""
<div><h2>Test</h2>
<div>Hi</div>
</div>
"""

// Parse
def config=new org.cyberneko.html.HTMLConfiguration()
config.setFeature("http://cyberneko.org/html/features/balance-tags/document-fragment",true)
def html=new XmlSlurper(new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()).parseText(text)          

// Output
def printNode(NodeChild node) {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    writer << new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
        mkp.declareNamespace('':node[0].namespaceURI())
        mkp.yield node
    }
    new XmlNodePrinter().print(new XmlParser().parseText(writer.toString()))
}
printNode(html)
```

Output:

```
<HTML>
  <tag0:HEAD xmlns:tag0="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"/>
  <BODY>
    <DIV>
      <H2>
        Test
      </H2>
      <DIV>
        Hi
      </DIV>
    </DIV>
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call setFeature on the parser object directly, like so:

```
@Grab(group='net.sourceforge.nekohtml', module='nekohtml', version='1.9.14')

import groovy.xml.MarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.util.XmlNodePrinter
import groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild


def text="""
<div><h2>Test</h2>
<div>Hi</div>
</div>
"""

// Parse
def parser=new org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser()
parser.setFeature("http://cyberneko.org/html/features/balance-tags/document-fragment",true)
def html=new XmlSlurper(parser).parseText(text)          

// Output
def printNode(NodeChild node) {
    def writer = new StringWriter()
    writer << new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
        mkp.declareNamespace('':node[0].namespaceURI())
        mkp.yield node
    }
    new XmlNodePrinter().print(new XmlParser().parseText(writer.toString()))
}
printNode(html)
```