# How can I transform some HTML fragment into XHTML using groovy?

Tags: html, xhtml, groovy

I have an input `String` containing some HTML fragment like the following example

```
I would have enever thought that <b>those infamous tags</b>, 
born in the <abbr title="Don't like that acronym">SGML</abbr> realm,
would make their way into the web of objects that we now experience.
```

Obviously, real one is by far more complex (including links, iamges, divs, and so on), and I would like to write a method having the following prototype

```
String toXHTML(String html) {
     // What do I have to write here ?
}
```

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3024488/xmlslurper-nekohtml-document-fragment-parsing-no-html-or-body-tags-wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a description of the input format, it will probably be some html-like stuff.
Parsing such a mess gets ugly quickly. But it looks like someone else did a good job already:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy
@Grapes(
    @Grab(group='jtidy', module='jtidy', version='4aug2000r7-dev')
)
import org.w3c.tidy.*
def tidy = new Tidy()
tidy.parse(System.in, System.out)
```

Use the force, Riduidel.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this: http://blog.foosion.org/2008/06/09/parse-html-the-groovy-way/
It might be something you are looking for.

Comment: http://www.webapp-blogger.de/2011/07/the-groovy-way-daten-aus-html-extrahieren/ is the original German